# Can I branch before committing to git?

Tags: git

I accidentally forgot to branch before making changes to code.
I have not committed anything.

If I branch, will the code follow me to the new branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you have not committed your changes yet. You can create a new branch and all changes made will be passed to that branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be 100% clean, I'd say the proper way is to go for

- `git stash`
- `git branch new_branch`
- `git stash pop`

(Although I prefer `git push master:new_branch` to create a new branch, and then track it with `git checkout -t origin/new_branch`)

Comment: This is unnecessary. If you just do `git branch new_branch`, the new branch points to the current `HEAD`, thus `stash` + `stash pop` never has any effects.